# Satellizer and angular-permission interop

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use both angular-permission and Satellizer for role based authentication functionality. The idea is for Satellizer to go get a token from the API and angular-permission to determine the role based on said token.

app.js:

```
.run(function(PermRoleStore, $auth) {
    PermRoleStore.defineManyRoles({
        'USER' : function() { return $auth.isAuthenticated('USER'); },
        'ADMIN' : function() { return $auth.isAuthenticated('ADMIN'); }
    });
    console.log(PermRoleStore.getStore());
})


.config(function ($authProvider, $stateProvider) {

        // USER AUTHORIZED STATES
        $stateProvider.state('Dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'Dashboard',
            data: {
                permissions: {
                    only: ['USER'],
                    redirectTo: function() {
                        return {
                            state: 'signup',
                            options: {
                                reload: true
                            }
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        })
});
```

$auth.isAuthenticated:

```
    isAuthenticated = function(roleArg) {
      var token = storage.get(tokenName);

      if (roleArg === null || 'undefined') {
        roleArg = 'ANONYMOUS';
      }

      var role = token.role;
      if (roleArg != role) {
        console.log('role: ' + role);
        console.log('roleArg: ' + roleArg);
        console.log('Permission denied');
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
    };
```

The problem I am having is I don't even see the PermRoleStore methods attempting to try and resolve. The app loads normally however it acts as if it is not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you forgot to

```
return true;
```

in `$auth.isAuthenticated`.

For debugging, can you give us a plunker example? I would debug inside `isAuthenticated` with

```
console.log(store);
```

to check the permission store data.
Try:

```
PermPermissionStore.getStore();
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by console.log(store)

Comment: I meant, you should debug the data inside `PermPermissionStore.getStore()` to check, if your permissions are set initially

Answer (score 0):

Did you try save user role to data key in satellizer JWT at the backend and access to that JWT data through `$auth.getPayload()` function.

```
.run(function (PermRoleStore, $auth) {
PermRoleStore    
.defineRole('ADMIN', function () {
  if($auth.getPayload()) {

  if ($auth.getPayload().data.role === 'ADMIN') {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
else {
  return false;
}
});
})
```